# Can't get fullname properly, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, constructor

Can someone explain why I am getting:

```
Test Passed: Value == 'Clint Eastwood'
No Last Name
Expected: 'Clint', instead got: 'Clint '
No First Name
Expected: 'Eastwood', instead got: ' Eastwood'
No First or Last Name
Expected: '', instead got: ' '
```

That's my code :

```html
constructor(firstName,lastName){
      this.lastName =lastName;
      this.firstName =firstName; 
    }
  
  getFullName()  {
     return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
      }
  
}
```

Comment: Because you don't deal correctly with the possibility that one or both of first and last name might be missing. *Read the output*, it tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to look what part of the name is setted.

```
getFullName()  {
      let result  = '';
      if (this.firstName) {
        result = this.firstName;
        if  (this.lastName)
          result += " " + this.lastName;
      }
      else if (this.lastName)
          result = this.lastName;
      return result;
 }
```